# Отслеживание движения пальца по элементам экрана

Tags: java, android, view, ontouchlistener

Пользователь водит пальцем по экрану. Необходимо определить, по каким элементам он провел пальцем.

Я назначил `OnTouchListener` нескольким EditText – текст изменяется только в том, по которому провели пальцем первым.

```
btn1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
            etditText.setText("text"); 
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Как сделать так, чтобы текст менялся во всех элементах, по которым пользователь провел пальцем?

Comment: Как вариант, нужно вешать слушатель на родителя и в цикле перебирать прямоугольники "детей" с анализом попадания.